# How to copy Kaspersky pure 3.0 virus definitions update to another computer?

Tags: anti-virus

I'm looking for a way of applying updates for Kaspersky pure 3.0 accross 5 computers without having to download the same files on all 5 computers. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Using a proxy server with a cache would achieve this?

Comment: how can tell me full process

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I am not a user of Kaspersky.

1. But I would like suggest you  You should check there

   " C:Documents and SettingsAll UsersApplication DataKaspersky LabKAV
   for Workstations5.0Bases "

   Then compare contents on both computers, and if they are different
   try to copy from new to old. Please disable Kaspersky During this
   process
2. You can also use another way-
   Download the latest version of Update Utility-
   Run KasperskyUpdater.exe
   Open this update--
   Click on Setting(Right on Panel)
      ---Click Update --- Now Click Setting ---- Select Source tab  ---- Add folder (where you want save update database)-- check this check box uncheck another check box-- click apply-- ok-- now click update-- start--
   I wish You will success to update another computer Kaspersky with same database file

Thanks